# Keyboard lagging in some applications but not all

Tags: keyboard, lenovo

My problem is that keyboard input is very slow in some applications. At the same time other applications work just fine.

I recently installed Joplin note taking app and typing is next to impossible because it takes several seconds for each character to appear when I type. Every other app works just fine. This same problem happens sometimes using Hyper terminal and it used to happen with 1Password but not anymore for some time.

I have looked for an answer but with no help. I have checked the **settings - Universal Access - Typing Assist** settings but with no help. I have also changed my USB mouse dongle to another port, no help. Tried to work with the laptop keyboard without USB keyboard.

The problem appears with and without Bluetooth keyboard and/or mouse.

My setting is:

- Lenovo X1 gen8 laptop with External Lenovo monitor
- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- System language is English but keyboard layout is Finnish (winkeys)
- GNOME version 3.36.8

Comment: Log into a different user account... create one if you don't have one... and see if the problem occurs there. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.